# Kudan: macos app couldn't use facetime camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan

I'm using unity and kudan to develop AR app for mac os.
But i can't use the camera (both facetime camera and  usb camera) when running app.
There's no problem when run on ios or android.
How can i fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Unity's Play Mode, make sure that you have generated yourself a Kudan key for the Unity Editor. You should usually see an error message in the log indicating if this is an issue.

You can generate your key at https://www.kudan.eu/api/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It work fine in Play Mode but the the exported macOS app (.app file) can't use the camera

Comment: On the desktops only Play Mode is currently supported.